# Dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been looking to create a dictionary from two set lists. I understand how to do this if I want each item in each list to be marked key and value for example:

```
list_one = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_two = ['1', '2', '3']
dictionary = dict(zip(list_one, list_two))
print dictionary
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

However I'm looking to use all the items in list_two as values for the first item in list_one. This would then hit another loop and item in list_one will change and so will the items in list_two.

Hope this makes sense.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Code used to create lists

```
def local_file(domain, user_list):
    cmd = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/FO", "CSV"])
    tasks = csv.DictReader(cmd.splitlines(), dialect="excel")

    image_name = set()
    users = set()
    for task in tasks:
        if task['User Name'] == 'N/A': continue
        task_domain, task_user = task['User Name'].split('\\')
        if task_user in task['User Name']:
            image_name.add(task['Image Name'])
        else:
            pass
        if domain == task_domain and task_user in user_list:
            users.add(task['User Name'])
    sorted(image_name)
    print "Users found:\n"
    print '\n'.join(users)
    print "\nRuning the following services and applications.\n"
    print '\n'.join(image_name)
    if arguments['--app'] and arguments['--output'] == True:
        keys = users
        key_values = image_name
        dictionary = dict(zip(list_one, list_two))
        print dictionary
    elif arguments['--output'] == True:
        return users
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: What would your result dictionary look like? An example of expected result would help clarify.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: expected results `{'c': ['8', '9', '10'], 'b': ['5', '6', '7'], 'a': ['1', '2', '3']}`

Comment: if `list_two` is a list of lists your original code would work just fine

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
>>> list_one = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list_two = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> {item: list_two[:] for item in list_one}
{'c': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['1', '2', '3'], 'a': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

For Python 2.6 and earlier:

```
>>> dict((item, list_two[:]) for item in list_one)
{'c': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['1', '2', '3'], 'a': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Note that `[:]` is required to create a shallow copy of the list, otherwise all values will point to the same list object.

**Update:**

As per your comment `list_two` will change during the iteration, here I've used an iterator to get the new value for `list_two` during the iteration:

```
>>> out = {}
>>> it = iter([['1', '2', '3'], ['5', '6', '7'], ['8', '9', '10']])
>>> list_two = next(it)  #here `next` can be your own function.
>>> for k in list_one:
        out[k] = list_two
        list_two = next(it)  #update list_two with the new value.

 >>> out
{'c': ['8', '9', '10'], 'b': ['5', '6', '7'], 'a': ['1', '2', '3']}

#or

>>> it = iter([['1', '2', '3'], ['5', '6', '7'], ['8', '9', '10']])
>>> out = {}
>>> for k in list_one:
        list_two = next(it)  #fetch the value of `list_two`
        out[k] = list_two
```

Comment: Maybe, but I'm suspicious of the "hit another loop and magic change happens" clause. A generator would probably be better because it can absorb environmental changes.

Comment: Thanks this looks like it will work, however I will need to write the function to get this working with it. might take me some time iNoob by name iNoob by nature ^_^

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what's updating list two. Until we do, we can only guess. Idiomatically, whatever gets the values should be an iterable (so that you can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#next)).

```
res = {}
for k in list_one:
  res[k] = next(lists_two)
```

or

```
res = {k:next(lists_two) for k in list_one}
```

if you have Python 2.7 or higher.

For an example that would have the same result as your comment, using `grouper` from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

lists_two = grouper(range(3*len(list_one)), 3)
res = {k:next(lists_two) for k in list_one}
```

Comment: ill add the function code im using to create the lists into my answer